# How do I start a community wiki question? - E.g., "JOIN MongoDB collections with MySQL tables?"

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

The attempt got blocked pretty quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64512473

So I assume you don't like community wiki style questions/answers(?).

(It was a problem I wanted solved, and no Stack Overflow answer I could find solved it… but many were asked, so it made sense to write up the question and provide the answer at once… isn't that the point of a community wiki?)

**How should one ask questions, with the intent of the answer becoming community wiki?**

EDIT: It looks like a bug in notifications, but I am not going to start a new thread, because if this one is any indication, it'll just drop my reputation points even lower.

[image: Notification shows "Hooray, this question was reopened"]

Comment: Might want to read up on [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) as well

Comment: [aside] Seems like a bad idea to even of asked/answered on StackOverflow and asked on meta… all it does is drop my rep dramatically. Asking on meta just brought further downvotes to stackoverflow. :\

Comment: It's known as the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). If you draw attention to questions people vote on them. If it's a good question you can end up with lots of upvotes.

Comment: Oh and there's no bug in notifications. You're notified of your achievements, getting downvoted is not an achievement. Notifications will start again once you exceed your previous maximum rep.

Comment: Questions should not be filled with meta information.

Comment: @RobertLongson "Hooray, this question was reopened! Anyone can answer it now." - Checking the question shows it as Closed and deleted. Clearly not a "Hooray" situation.

Answer (score 15):

Questions asked as community-wiki have the same quality requirements as any other questions so...

> I've seen a bunch of questions on Stack Overflow over the years asking a similar question.

That doesn't add anything to the question so should be deleted.

> Re-asking, with the intent that the accepted answer becomes a wiki.

And this isn't a question at all.

Ask a proper question detailing the problem, what the pre-conditions are, and maybe why this is a problem that needs solving i.e. what trips you up in the existing documentation on the subject etc.

Your answer wasn't a high quality answer either. We want answers to be self contained i.e. you read them here. If you're going to mention some software that can be used to solve the problem then you'd need to explain how that software is configured or provide an example of the integration code you'd need to write to cover the use case in the question.